Conformally Mapping $\left\{z : |z|\leq \frac{1}{2}\right\}$ onto $\left\{w: \left|w-\frac{10}{3}i\right|\leq \frac{8}{3}\right\}$
I was looking through the solution of an old complex analysis qualifying exam and came across the following statement:
$w = \frac{2i(1+z)}{1-z}$ $\big($that is the inverse of $z = \frac{w-2i}{w+2i}\big)$ is a conformal mapping of $\left\{z : |z|\leq \frac{1}{2}\right\}$ onto $\left\{w: \left|w-\frac{10}{3}i\right|\leq \frac{8}{3}\right\}.$
How exactly does $w = \frac{2i(1+z)}{1-z}$ conformally map $\left\{z : |z|\leq \frac{1}{2}\right\}$ onto $\left\{w: \left|w-\frac{10}{3}i\right|\leq \frac{8}{3}\right\}$?
edit: typo with incorrect inequality.

I don't think this is possible.   One set is compact, the other isn't.   A continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff is a homeomorphism.

@noupstairs Oh boy, I just noticed the typo with the inequality. I have edited my post. That was my bad, I typed up the post late last night...

The map $f:z\mapsto\frac{2i(1+z)}{1-z}$ is defined on $U=\mathbb{C}-\{1\}$ and its derivative is nonzero on $U$, hence defines a conformal mapping of $U$ onto its image which is $V=\mathbb{C}-\{2i\}$. This map is a bijection as we can explicitly write down its inverse. In particular, it is one-to-one.
Let $A=\{z:|z|\leq\frac{1}{2}\}$ and $B=\{w:\left|w-\frac{10}{3}i\right|\leq\frac{8}{3}\}$.
We have :
$w\in B\iff\left|w-\frac{10}{3}i\right|\leq\frac{8}{3}$
$\iff\left|\frac{1+z}{1-z}-\frac{5}{3}\right|\leq\frac{4}{3}$
$\iff\left|\frac{8z-2}{3(1-z)}\right|\leq\frac{4}{3}$
$\iff\left|4z-1\right|\leq2\left|z-1\right|$
$\iff\left|4z-1\right|^2\leq(2\left|z-1\right|)^2$ because both are positive
$\iff(4z-1)(4\overline{z}-1)\leq4(z-1)(\overline{z}-1)$
$\iff|z|^2\leq\frac{1}{4}$
$\iff|z|\leq\frac{1}{2}$ again by positivity
$\iff z \in A$
Thus $f$ restricts to a conformal mapping of $A$ onto $B$.
